# How can we test package-private class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I am reading book `Effective Java`, in `Item 13: Minimize the accessibility of classes and members`, it mentioned that:

> To facilitate testing, you may be tempted to make a class, interface, or member more accessible. This is fine up to a point. it is acceptable to make a private member of a public class package-private in order to test it, but it is not acceptable to raise the accessibility any higher than that. In other words, it is not acceptable to make a class, interface, or member a part of packages's exported API to facilitate testing.

I know we should encapsulate members, hiding information from clients, we can test them by accessing the class with setters and getters, but
How should I understand make class package-private accessible, if so How to test it?

Answer (score 27):

Basically it means that your tester class should reside in the same package as your tested class. That would make your tested class and all package protected members and methods accessible to your testing class. The classes may be located under different roots: your tested class may be under `src/main/java/myrootpackage/first/second/MyClass.java` and your testing class may be located under `src/test/java/myrootpackage/first/second/MyClassTester.java`.

Comment: it makes sense and probbabliy it is the only way to do test on the package-private classes. thanks! +1

Comment: My current setting follows `src.main.java.myrootpackage.first.MyClass.java` and `src.test.java.myrootpackage.first.test.MyClassTest.java`, but the test class can't find the source class. If I remove the `test` and put the test case under `src.test.java.myrootpackage.first.MyClassTest.java` then it works.

Comment: You are correct, if your method that you want to test is defined as protected (or package private i.e. no keyword) then your test class must be in the same package. in your settings part of the path "src.main.java" and "src.test.java" are not part of the package. So, you had your class in package "myrootpackage.first" and your testing class in "myrootpackage.first.test". Once you moved your testing class in "myrootpackage.first" it sees the protected or package private members of your class. Also you can see the package in the first line of your class "package myrootpackage.first"

Comment: For both your class and your testing class those must be the same

Comment: In C# package-protected are internal and  you can easily expose the same to your test project, simply by typing [assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyTests")] into your actual code package project. I wish if Java has one too. If you read further on page 75 Joshua says "Luckily, it isn’t necessary either because
tests can be made to run as part of the package being tested, thus gaining access to its package-private elements." I think there is no possibilities at this stage.

Comment: This answer is very misleading and confusing. The tested class might be src/main/java/pkg1/pkg2/MyClass.java, and the test code would be in src/test/java/pkg1/pkg2/MyClassTest.java. The answer adds a '.MyClass.' which is wrong, uses the same word in different contexts ('root'), those dots don't make sense, and the directory structure is non-conventional.

Answer (score 5):

I guess what the author means is that instead of

```
package my.package;

class TestableClass {
     private String property;
}
```

You can change the visibility to

```
package my.package;

class TestableClass {
    String property;
}
```

With the second implementation you can access the property from a test in the package `my.package` like

```
package my.package;

class TestableClassTest {
    // ...
}
```

At the same time, a subclass cannot access the property - that's the benefit comapred to `protected`.

Comment: Michael, thanks for your reply. I have thought about this but it is not convenient to run all tests automatically. Unfortunately, it is impossible to separate the test classes files into a different package. +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide details (that are required for your tests) of your class, you could use [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) to easily generate an appropriate getter-Method with package-level access, which would allow reading (from test classes in same package) but prevent mutation (everywhere) of a certain field.

```
public class SimpleRetryStrategy implements RetryStrategy {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    private final int maxRetries;
```