# Testing a private method in unit testing

Tags: java, junit

I know the answer to this question is: you do not test private method but only the public method that will eventually lead to that private method invocation.

BUT
In my case, the public method actually starting up a consumer/connection to kafka, so i only want to test the logic done when a kafka message is received.
I do not want to make the logic method public as no one will use it out side of the kafka infrastructure, but still i want to unit test the logic done there.

What is the best practice solution? I can change the code if need be

Heres some examples:

the private method in question

```
 private void handleConsumerRecord(ConsumerRecord<PK, byte[]> cr, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws IOException {
//logic to be tested
}
```

the private method that calls the private logic method

```
/**
     * Initialize the kafka message listener
     */
    private void initConsumerMessageListenerContainer(ProducerFactory<PK, V> producerFactory) {
        if (!processAsBatch) {
            // start a acknowledge message listener to allow the manual commit
            acknowledgingMessageListener =  (cr, acknowledgment) -> {
                try {
                    handleConsumerRecord(cr, acknowledgment);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Failed to handle consumed message, commiting message and performing irrecoverableException actions");
                    exceptionHandlerManager.getIrrecoverableExceptionHandler().performAction(null, cr.value(), cr.topic(), cr.key());
                }
            };

            // start and initialize the consumer container
            container = initContainer(acknowledgingMessageListener, producerFactory);
}
```

and this is the public method that starts everything

```
/**
     * Start the message consumer
     * The record event will be delegate on the onMessage()
     */
    public void start(ProducerFactory<PK, V> producerFactory) {
        initConsumerMessageListenerContainer(producerFactory);
        container.start();
    }
```

The unit test i tried to write

```
    kafkaByteArrConsumer.getAcknowledgingMessageListener().onMessage(record, acknowledgment);
        doThrow(TemporaryException.class).when(kafkaByteArrConsumer).getConsumerMessageLogic().onMessage(record.value(), acknowledgment);
        Mockito.verify(exceptionHandlerManager.getTemporaryExceptionHandler(), Mockito.times(1))
                .performAction();
```

As you can see, the `getAcknowledgingMessageListener` will not be initialized by the `initConsumerMessageListenerContainer()` and therefore i wont be able to access the handleConsumer method when mocking `.getConsumerMessageLogic().onMessage`

(which is called by the //some logic to be tested part)

Comment: I think some unit test frameworks can test private methods.  Reflection and a permissive security manager will allow this.  OTOH I often make a private method package-private so that it can be called directly with a test harness (that is itself in the same package).  I add a note that a method is package-private "only for testing" in those cases.

Comment: Yes im aware that PowerMock can test a private method... but i wanted the best practice solution, i cant seem to think about a design change that will solve it, and im sure there is one.

Answer (score 1):

A good compromise would be to change your method to protected or even to package-private, and then have your unit test located in the same package. The unit-test class doesn't have to reside under the same root. Say your source resides under "source" folder and tests reside under "test" folder. Just have the testing class reside in the same package. A very detailed answer could be found in this question: [How can we test package-private class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255972/how-can-we-test-package-private-class/42256510#42256510)
. Your question may be a duplicate of that question

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are people who use PowerMock to test private methods etc. but I always recommend to avoid that. Maybe you should consider change your logic a little there or even better consider Kafka MockConsumer etc.

Comment: I considered using MockConsumer(the spring boot variation), my problem is that i created a kafka infrastructure for my programmers to use without any clue about kafka, i create a builder and made the entire configuration a bit dumb proof. and now i pay in the flexibility of the kafka support community... I fear my only solution is to actually make that method public... which is bad practice in my opinion...

Comment: then you could still test start public method and maybe provide only mock for producerFactory, if you want avoid extracting your handleConsumerRecord logic to public.