# How do I correctly design my classes so that internal logic is unit testable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, testing

I'm struggling to figure out how to correctly design code in a large codebase so that pieces of internal logic can be easily testable. Here's a made up example:

```
public class SomeService
{
    public SomeService(){}
    
    public DoThingA(bool flagA)
    {
        // lots of logic 
        ...

        // eventually get some object, either through a request or some other way
        ObjectA response = makeSomeHttpRequest();
        
        // get some value based on the object and some other fields
        var url = GenerateUrl(response, flagA);

        // more logic
    }
    
    private string GenerateUrl(ObjectA response, bool flagA)
    {
        if (response.field1 == "foo" && flagA)
        {
            return "plugh.com";
            
        }
        else if (response.field1 == "bar")
        {
            return "xyzzy.com";
        }
        else
        {
            return "thud.com";
        }
    }
}
```

If I wanted to write a unit test to handle the logic of `GenerateUrl`, how would I do that?

- It might not be easy to figure out the response of `GenerateUrl` by calling DoThingA, so I don't want to do that
- The logic for `GenerateUrl` is relatively small and internal logic for DoThingA(), so I'd prefer not to make it public just for testing
- I could move the logic of GenerateUrl into it's own class that SomeService depends on, but in a large codebase that will result in 100s of very tiny classes that maybe only have a few lines of logic

So what's the correct way to structure this so I can test some internal logic? Maybe GenerateUrl is actually some validation logic or really just any single function that i'd want to have unit tests around.

Comment: `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("yourTestAssembly")]`.

Comment: @Dai whoa, that looks useful! Do you know offhand if something like this exists for Java/C++/etc? Not looking for the specifics if yes, just trying to learn how to do this in a way that could apply elsewhere and want to make sure this isn't C# only magic

Comment: C++ doesn't work like that (C++ doesn't support "exports" or any kind of ABI: you can't reuse a C++ class from a compiled program just-like-that in another C++ project: C++ requires source-level code-reuse (unless you count COM...), while Java is much more like C#/.NET (e.g. Java's `package-private` is akin to C#'s `internal`) [but for testing Java requires your test code to live in the same package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255972/how-can-we-test-package-private-class). C#/.NET definitely has the better devX here than Java (well, that's _always_ been the case, heh)

Comment: Test classes through their public interface, because that's how they're going to be used. Personally, I prefer to write tests _first_ to help design the components I need in an application.

Comment: Also, writing tests first does, by definition, lead to code that's easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to testing private/internal logic, I have seen many opinions and many approaches to this issue. Often one may hear about testing only the public API, because it is the one that will be made available to external components, and if the internal mechanisms (which are *just a implementation detail*) contain bugs it should come out in testing the public API, but often the reality is different. Looking at the example given, you can take (at least) two approaches.

The first would be to replace the private API with internal and use the `InternalsVisibleTo` functionality to be able to refer to internal code fragments from the project containing the tests.

Add this to the project (.csproj file) that you want to test

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="MyProject.Tests" />
</ItemGroup>
```

or use the attribute in any file in the given assembly

```cs
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Tests")]
```

The second approach could be to test the functionality called inside the externally inaccessible API. Those method could be a part of a different public API

I also recommend taking a look at this post on [Coding Journeyman by Julien Fiaffé](https://codingjourneyman.com/2015/07/27/unit-tests-and-protected-methods/)